# how to get Tree meta data in fancytree jquery

Tags: jquery, css, fancytree

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  source: [
    {title: "Node 1", key: "1"},
    {title: "Folder 2", key: "2", folder: true, children: [
      {title: "Node 2.1", key: "3", myOwnAttr: "abc"},
      {title: "Node 2.2", key: "4"}
    ]}
  ],
  ...
};
```

Now how can i get this `myOwnAttr` value when node is activate? 
If possible then give me working example not written solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the active node from tree:

```
var node = $("#tree").fancytree("getActiveNode");
```

The *data* object will hold the metadata from your tree, to get your custom attribute values you call it like this:

```
console.log(node.data.myOwnAttr);
```

Reference: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData#passing-data-with-the-source-option

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!